# How can I fix my program to not crash if I run any character that is not alphabetical?

Tags: c, cs50

So I am trying to write code that will allow me to count the number of letters a user has entered.
My code runs well if I simply type one word.
The moment that I include any character that is not a letter, my terminal stops working.

What can I do to fix it?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int count_letters(string text);

int main(void)
{
    string text = get_string("text? ");
    int letters = count_letters(text);

    printf("%i letters\n", letters);
}

int count_letters(string text)
{
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        if (isalpha(text[i]))
        {
            i++;
        }
        else if (isspace(text[i]))
        {
            i = + 0;
        }
        else
        {
            i = +0;
        }
    } while (text[i] != 0);

    return i;
}
```

Comment: Is `i` the index of the string, or is `i` the count of alphabetic characters? It can only be both if the string is all alphabetic characters...

Comment: Does changing your `i = + 0;` to `i += 0;` correct the issue. Change both the `else if` and the `else`.

Comment: Also why are you setting `i` to 0 when the character is not an alphabet?

Comment: @NorSer Consider when/whether the loop will end with your proposed solution.

Comment: @Yunnosch What answer?

Comment: I did not say "answer". I was referring to the only thing you wrote here. @NorSer

Comment: `i = + 0` probably does not mean what think it means.

Comment: If you want to recognise digits as well `isalnum` might preferrable...

Comment: As far as I can see your application actually doesn't crash, it's just caught in an endless loop, as by resetting `i` to 0 you restart iterating over the string from start...

Comment: Why do you reset `i` to 0 at all? Would you want to terminate words to make them independent (embedded) strings? Then you'd likely need `*i = 0;`. Would you want to count words separately, or possibly create a list of word length? Then you need, apart from the one proposed in the answers given already, yet additional variables.

Comment: Note that negative counts are meaningless anyway – alike as negative indices (and you won't iterate backwards, would you???). An unsigned return type (and index variable type) would reflect that fact. Even though in practice unlikely that any length might exceed (unsigned) int, semantically correct would actually be `size_t` (from `stddef.h`, as it would allow to hold indices into and counts of any (theoretically) allocatable strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` is the `do ... while` counter, do not use it to count the number of letters, use another variable, something like:

```
int count_letters(string text)
{
    int i = 0, letters = 0;
    do
    {
        if (isalpha((unsigned char)text[i]))
        {
            letters++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    while (text[i] != 0);
    return letters;
}
```

Notice that with your approach the loop is also testing the `NUL` terminator in an empty string, use a `while` loop instead to exit the loop as soon as the `NUL` is found:

```
int count_letters(string text)
{
    int letters = 0;
    while (*text)
    {
        if (isalpha((unsigned char)*text))
        {
            letters++;
        }
        text++;
    }
    return letters;
}
```

Comment: I personally rather prefer for loops to keep the increment in the loop header: `for(; *text; ++text) { ... }`

Comment: And, if the parameter `text` holds the value NULL???

Comment: @Aconcagua Just FYI... At this stage of CS50, pointer arithmetic is still unknown to the students... Just FYI... `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 Well, it was introduced in the while loop already... Still the for loop appears favourable to me even without pointer arithmetic, in your case (with added check for null – where I personally would prefer just having `if(text) {...}`) `for(int i = 0; text[i]; ++i)`, this time even with the advantage of limiting the scope of `i` to the loop itself. Actually they *do* use pointer arithmetics already, by the way (`*(text + i)`), just a little bit hidden behind syntactic sugar ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua Stylistic differences... Nothing new... Array notation is good for this level, but incrementing a pointer has not been covered and could be confusing. Just that... All good...

Comment: @Fe2O3 Not critisising. Just want to show the *alternatives* and indicating the advantages of, might be helpful for the QA ;) In the end it is her/him to decide anyway (-> 'I personally' – assumed to give that information implicitly, but apparently doesn't… – apparently need to keep an eye on more clear/obvious/precise wording).

Comment: @Fe2O3 _And, if the parameter text holds the value NULL???_ Good point, personally I prefer to follow the C API style where functions do not check if `NULL` has been passed and instead check that `get_string` does not return `NULL` on the line where it is called (which the OP does not do in his code).- So OP, always check the result of your functions, in your case : `if ((text = get_string("text? ")) != NULL) printf("%i letters\n", count_letters(text));`

Comment: @DavidRanieri When answering these things with code, I try to accentuate "trust no-one, not even yourself!" Too many hours lost to _blind trust_ of the obvious mischief maker... the guy in the mirror... `:-)`

Comment: @DavidRanieri - would you be so kind as to explain the use of "unsigned char" . I've never used it before and I would like to understand the use of it better please.

Comment: @Sizwe all functions in `ctype.h` (toupper(), tolower() and all isxxxxx()) requires a cast to `unsigned char` before being passed: _**The header declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping characters. In all cases the argument is an int, the value of which shall be representable as an unsigned char or shall equal the value of the macro EOF. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.**_

Answer (score 0):

Consider what happens in your loop: `i` only increments when the character at `text[i]` is an alphabetic character. Otherwise it resets to zero.

Thus, the loop will never complete for a string that is not entirely alphabetic characters because the loop will "reset" to the beginning with ever non-alphabetic character.

We can increment an index from zero until the character at that index in the string is the null-terminator of zero (which is false in C).

```
int count_letters(string text) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; text[i]; i++) {
        if (isalpha(text[i])) count++;
    } 

    return count;
}
```

We can however, use pointers to iterate over your string, taking advantage of the detection of the null terminator to terminate the loop. If each character is an alphabetic character, increment a counter. A for loop can handle giving you a temp pointer and initializing it, testing for termination of the loop and incrementing the pointer.

```
int count_letters(string text) {
    int count = 0;

    for (char *ch = text; *ch; ch++) {
        if (isalpha(*ch)) count++;
    } 

    return count;
}
```

As `text` is a pointer passed by value (being hidden by CS50's `string` typedef), it can be modified without affecting the original string as long as we don't dereference and modify the individual characters, so we can avoid the extra char pointer.

```
int count_letters(string text) {
    int count = 0;

    for (; *text; text++) {
        if (isalpha(*text)) count++;
    } 

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Provided the typedef is not a pointer to const (why the hell did they do this typedef stupidity at all???), then depending on if we yet need the original string or not it might even be safe to modify it ;)

Comment: I'll write the same thing here... FYI... CS50 students have not yet encountered pointer arithmetic... Just FYI... `:-)`

Comment: Just noticing: `isalpha` requires a cast to `unsigned char` (unless `char` being unsigned or character range not exceeding [0; 127] is guaranteed by other means) to avoid securely avoid undefined behaviour (see [other anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73809699/1312382).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comment, `i` cannot serve two purposes (index and counter) except for the special case of a string comprised of **only** letters.

Below is a compact function that counts 'hits' when `isalpha()` has returned a non-zero value (indicating the current letter is in the range "A-Za-z").

The unusual "!!" transforms the non-zero positive value into C's `true` (or `false`) having values of 1 (or 0) respectively. Thusly, the value of 1 or 0 is appropriately added to the accumulator to be returned to the caller.

```
int count_letters( string text ) {
    int i = 0, cnt = 0;

    if( text != NULL ) // trust is good, testing is better
        while( text[i] )
            cnt += !!isalpha( (unsigned char)text[i++] );

    return cnt;
}
```

EDIT and Credit: @Aconcagua for pointing out the need for casting each char to `unsigned char` to avoid UB.

Comment: @Aconcagua When this student reaches that level in the course (size_t), then, yes... At this level, `int` is sufficient... The "not-not" used here is a glimpse of the future and incentive to **really** master the syntax... Six and half-a-dozen, eh?

Comment: @Aconcagua If _newbies_ had it hammered into them to test and not to "_assume_" (and even use print debugging), there would be a 90% drop in SO questions. (And, graduating students would be aware of the pitfalls...)

Comment: Just noticing: `isalpha` requires a cast to `unsigned char` (unless `char` being unsigned or character range not exceeding [0; 127] is guaranteed by other means) to avoid securely avoid undefined behaviour (see [other anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73809699/1312382).